# Production deploy of PlayFramework 2 apps

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am interested on how people deploy Play2 apps to production. 
I am not interested in PaaS solutions like Heroku which are fantastic but I am currently looking at a stand alone solution on linux hosts.

1. Do you install Play2 on the linux server or do you just install sbt?
2. Do you build the project on a CI server and use the Play stage task to generate the target which then gets copied to the production server on release?
3. Do you install git on the prod server pulling the code from head and building it using either play or sbt and running the start generated from the stage command?

Are there other solutions to package and deploy Play2 projects?

Answer (score 1):

We're using Play 2.1 on our current project (which consists of 4 applications now) and this is how it looks like:

1. We have an Ubuntu server with only Java installed on it.
2. We have a simple deployer application which swaps application.conf files (dev and prod), runs `play dist`, transfers the zip via scp to the ubuntu server, unpacks it there, shutdowns  current running apps, replaces them with the new ones and starts again.

Comment: So you run the "play dist" on your build server and copy over the zip file which I see now has the start and required libs. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Play2.1.2 on our app. Now I'm having the saming question about it.
I use Ubuntu, and there is a Tomcat and Nginx on it. Can I use play's netty to run it instead of using Play2War plugin to generate a war.